# Refresh view using ajax with parameters

Tags: 8, views, ajax

I use this code to refresh a view, but It reloads the view ignoring neither page number nor filters.

```
$('.view-id-name').trigger('RefreshView');
```

How could I pass parameters (page number, query filters, etc) to this call?